# Is changing an abstract member from protected to public a binary breaking change?

Tags: c#, .net, backwards-compatibility

Let's say I have a C# class:

```
public class Foo
{
    protected abstract void Bar();
}
```

I would like to make `Bar` public. Is this a **binary** breaking change?

I know that it is a **source** breaking change because a consumer who wrote:

```
public class Baz : Foo
{
    protected override void Bar() { ... }
}
```

Would get a compiler error: CS0507  'Baz.Bar()': cannot change access modifiers when overriding 'public' inherited member 'Foo.Bar()'

Comment: C# compiles to MSIL anyways, so I'm pretty sure compiler errors overrule everything else in this case since you don't get down into instruction set until interpretation occurs. As far as a true binary breaking change, it shouldn't "have" to be - interpretation on C# is what determines this though. The reason being is the virtual table for Baz could easily override the Bar method if allowed. Maybe I'm not understanding your question, but you don't get down to runtime binary until interpretation occurs in the first place, and you can't get to MSIL without the C# compiler.

Comment: @CaitLANJenner: the question is about external assemblies that are compiled before the change is made. Obviously the C# compiler would prevent you from recompiling it. This question is about what happens to a pre-existing DLL.

Comment: That makes much more sense. I'm under the impression the linker may panic in such situations.

Comment: AFAIK, override methods allowed to increase visibility of method, but not to reduce it.

Comment: Easy test...  Compile your original code into a simple assembly.  Consume it in another assembly.  Then make your change.  See what happens.